# How do you calculate gradient descent when you have a point which gives two different values?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient decent algorithm. The dataset on which I am working has points which are of a partial function I guess.

For example these are a subset of the dataset.

$(1, 10)$

$(2, 15)$

$(3, 35)$

$(3, 40)$

$(4, 34)$

$(5, 21)$

When it is 3, there can be two different values. How do I handle this? Thanks

Comment: you need a data preprocessing and eliminate all such points

Comment: The gradient is a property of functions, which are single-valued, so before you can apply gradient descent, you need to have a function. How you fix this is going to depend on your application and why you are getting multiple values. If it is computation error, then you need to reduce that error until it is managable. If your data is not being generated functionally, you need to figure out how to get a function applicable to your needs. We can't help you with that without a lot more information than you've given.

Comment: Often gradient descent in ML operates over *batches* when computing the updates. If this is a regression task, learning some $f_\theta$, then for a point $x$ mapping to two different $y$ values, the algo will likely learn to output something like $f_\theta(x)$ being near the average between the two $y$ values. In some cases, this is the best one can do assuming the data generating mechanism has some level of inherent stochasticity that is unavoidable. In other words, one option is to do nothing.

Comment: Thank you thats what I wanted to learn

Comment: @Thunfische I'll move my comment to an answer so you can get your question out of the unanswered list. (assuming it's mine you're referring to?) Btw if you don't use the `@username` in your comments, then other people won't see any notification of your response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often gradient descent in ML operates over batches when computing the updates. If this is a regression task, learning some $f_\theta$, then for a point $x$ mapping to two different $y$ values, the algo will likely learn to output something like $f_\theta(x)$ being near the average between the two $y$ values. In some cases, this is the best one can do assuming the data generating mechanism has some level of inherent stochasticity that is unavoidable. In other words, one option is to do nothing.